# Django make variable visible

Tags: python, django

I want to make variable visible in elif without making it global, is it possible in any other ways?

```
if query !=something:
    all_toys = Toys.objects.filter(user_name=request.user)
elif query2 != something:
    all_toys = all_toys.filter(amount=20)
```

second all_toys isn't visible, and i got this error django referenced before assignment.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What is this code trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm trying to create live search and it returns different filtered object

Comment: I think you are not understanding how `if` statements works in python. In your case when first condition is true code under other conditions will not be executed. Read https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements and http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_if_else.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to this is to create filter dictionary

```
filter_kw = {}
if query !=something:
    filter_kw['user_name'] = request.user
elif query2 != something:
    filter_kw['amount'] = 20
all_toys = Toys.objects.filter(**filter_kw)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you declare the value on top and use it in all conditions?

```
all_toys = Toys.objects.all()

if query != something:
    all_toys = all_toys.filter(...)
else:
    all_toys = all_toys.filter(...)
```

In your case, all_toys will not have been defined in the elif block

Comment: there are three inputs. 2 dropdowns and 1 text input what if user filter this object with all of them?

Comment: @I.Jokhadze  In that case just use multiple `if`s instead of elif. That will work better